# facebook login API: TypeError in all.js:95

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am developing a web app which uses the facebook API to login the user.
Everything worked fine until today, when suddently I started getting this strange error:

> Safari:
>       TypeError: 'false' is not a function (evaluating 'window.open(ea.url,ea.id,oa)') all.js:95
>
> Firefox: [19:10:17.325] TypeError: window.open is not a function @
>   http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js:95
>
> Chrome: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'open' of object [object global] is not a function
>   all.js:95

I cannot figure out what is wrong, even because the error is signaled in the all.js facebook javascript, which worked fine until some hours ago. 
Does someone have any cue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here I am in shame posting the cause my error: I had an

> open

object somewhere in my code and this led to the misinterpretation of the window.open variable.
So if you get a similar error, check your variables and namespaces.